# Proof of creation date with video metadata?

Tags: video, metadata, exif

Is there any way to prove without any doubt that a certain video was created on a certain date? Maybe something like EXIF data but for video file? This video is currently on an iPhone. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Metadata fields exist, but they are also editable ("...without any doubt...").

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to prove without a doubt as all files are editable. Some forensic photographers use old cameras that record directly to CD for this reason.

Try opening the movie file in a hex editor and looking through it for a timestamp. Often image/video dates are stored in text. You might be able to search for the year to speed the search up.

On Windows, HxD is a good hex editor.